# In Intellij, how do you safely refactor out continue statements from loops?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, refactoring

I hate `continue`s (and `break`s) in my java code but I'm not always the one that writes the code, so I was wondering if Intellij has a safe way to remove them from loops?  Here's a trivial example showing a for loop that prints odd numbers:

```
package com.sandbox;

import static java.util.Arrays.asList;

public class Sandbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Sandbox().run();
    }

    private void run() {
        for (Integer integer : asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)) {
            if (integer % 2 == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            System.out.println(integer);
        }
    }
}
```

How do I get rid of the `continue` without worrying if I broke my code?

Answer (score 5):

Alt+Enter on the if condition and choose "Invert If Condition". It removes "continue" in your example and in some others.

Comment: Hm I see.  It didn't on my real, non-trivial code.  But that's good to know it works in some situations.

Answer (score 2):

I've found out how to do this.  Highlight everything *inside* the for loop and extract into a method.  For example, highlight this:

```
        if (integer % 2 == 0) {
            continue;
        }
        System.out.println(integer);
```

And extract method and it will become this:

```
package com.sandbox;

import static java.util.Arrays.asList;

public class Sandbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Sandbox().run();
    }

    private void run() {
        for (Integer integer : asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)) {
            iterate(integer);
        }
    }

    private void iterate(Integer integer) {
        if (integer % 2 == 0) {
            return;
        }
        System.out.println(integer);
    }
}
```

---

Is this cleaner than before?  **No!**  And that's not the point.  Imagine this *wasn't* a trivial example.  Imagine you had code nested 10 braces deep inside a for loop and continues sprinkled all over.  The continues constantly prevent you from refactoring because you can't extract code that contains a continue into its own method since a `continue` is only syntactically correct in the context of a for loop.

This answer provides a *step* towards cleaner code, but sometimes you've got to make things a little messier before you can make them a lot cleaner.  This is such an example.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a "refactor". I would write it as: `for (..) { if (negate_the_previous_expression) { printIt(); } }`. I don't like continue or break (except in very particular cases).

Comment: I like many methods, but this (specific case) .. just Doesn't Seem Right to me :D That being said, I think it's a good answer insofar that it provides instructions required to perform a certain task.

Comment: @user2246674 You're not thinking beyond the "trivial example" I gave.  I was looking at code 10 braces deep with `continue`s sprinkled throughout it, often nested deeply in `if` statements.  Being able to remove the `continue`s is the first **step** to cleaning up the code.

Comment: I wouldn't fix it by turning a continue into a return. I'd fix it by removing the continue. If there is excessive nesting then this should likely be fixed, but really isn't related to the flow itself.

Comment: @user2246674 and how would you **safely** do that?

Comment: I've provided the equivalent rewrite that can be reasoned over: it really isn't different than a "return early" vs. ensuring all paths are paired. Unit tests and code coverage are very good at catching regressions.

Comment: @user2246674 I don't have unit tests or code coverage.  I inherited this code.  Now how would you **safely** rewrite the code?

Comment: @dnault if you've read "Working Effectively with Legacy Code", you'd note that it's usually impossible to unit test legacy code without changing it first.  Changing it first is dangerous.  He recommends using an IDE to refactor your code if you can trust the tool.  I trust Intellij with this.  It's a safe way to get the code into a unit testable state.